# $\cap\mathfrak{V}$ is a subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$ and let $\mathfrak{V}$ be a nonempty set of subspace of $V$. Then $\cap\mathfrak{V}$ is a subspace of $V$.

Proof. Note that $0\in U$ for any $U\in\mathfrak{V}$. Thus, $0\in\cap\mathfrak{V}$. Now, we need to show that $\cap\mathfrak{V}$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. But, **how? Can you help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b \in \cap \mathfrak{V}$. Then $a,b \in V_i$ for each $V_i \in \mathfrak{V}$. Therefore $a + b \in V_i$ for all $V_i \in \mathfrak{V}$ , hence 
$$a + b \in \cap \mathfrak{V} $$
since the $V_i$ are subspaces of the vectorspace $V$. (Note that this is basically what you did to prove $0 \in \cap \mathfrak{V}$).

Does this gives you an idea for the scalar multiplication?

Comment: Let $a\in\cap\mathfrak{V}$ and let $c$ be a scalar. Then, $a\in V_i$ for each $V_i\in\mathfrak{V}$. Thus, $ac\in V_i$ for all $V_i\in\mathfrak{V}$. Hence, $ac\in\cap\mathfrak{V}$. True?

Comment: @Kahler: Neatly done!

Comment: Glad to help you out!